# Django Caching and condition decorator

Tags: django, caching, last-modified

This is from the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/):

```
condition(etag_func=None, last_modified_func=None)
etag(etag_func)
last_modified(last_modified_func)

These decorators can be used to generate ETag and Last-Modified headers
```

and yet, this is also from [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/):

```
Additionally, the cache middleware automatically sets a few headers in each HttpResponse:
Sets the Last-Modified header to the current date/time when a fresh (uncached) version of the page is requested.
Sets the Expires header to the current date/time plus the defined CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS.
Sets the Cache-Control header to give a max age for the page -- again, from the CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS setting.
```

So I was wondering what value does Last-Modified takes when I use both sitewise caching and condition decorator.
Edit: And also, would you recommend using them both, or just using one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache middleware will only set the `ETag`, `Last-Modified` and `Expires` header if they are not already present (see the [patch_response_headers](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/utils/cache.py#L90) method that is called from [UpdateCacheMiddleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/middleware/cache.py#L107) ).

And since the decorators will be executed directly after the response is returned from the view, the decorator headers will be already present when the the middleware runs.

In short: `Last-Modified` will have the value from the condition/last_modified decorator.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but, which one do you think is best practice? Use them both, or let caching handle last modified?